# Why does this regex not work the way I want it?

Tags: regex

I have string like the following 'TextBoxKunde85_3_0', and i want to extract only the number part (including the underlines).
I created the following regex:

```
/^\w+(\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,3})$/
```

But for the example I provided above it retunrns '5_3_0' instead of '85_3_0'. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `\w` also matches digits *and* the underscore. It therefore swallows all input, but has to "give back" in order for the regex to satisfy:

```
# before matching
regex: |^\w+(\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,3})$
input: |TextBoxKunde85_3_0
# ^
regex: ^|\w+(\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,3})$
input: |TextBoxKunde85_3_0
# \w+
regex: ^\w+|(\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,3})$
input: TextBoxKunde85_3_0|
# \d{1,2}: no... Must give back
regex: ^\w+|(\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,3})$
input: TextBoxKunde85_3_|0
# \d{1,2}: match
regex: ^\w+(\d{1,2}|_\d{1,2}_\d{1,3})$
input: TextBoxKunde85_3_0|
# _: no, give back
# etc etc
```

Replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]` and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`\w+(\d{1,2})`: the first greedy globbing wins.

Here `\w+` will therefore eat the `8`.

Two solutions:

- Use non-greedy repetition after `\w`.
- Remove the `^\w+` part: you don't capture it…

Comment: @Lieven: Voting is anonymous, why do you think it's @fge?

Comment: @Lieven because of the abuse of the lazy quantifier -- the input is "one or more letters, followed by one or more digits, followed by...", therefore the input can be described in a way which does not require a lazy quantifier. This construct is used, overused, abused and misused.

Comment: @ge: can you explain why using non-greedy repetition is bad?

Comment: @Benoit - Three answers within a minute, I upvoted all of them and two out of three getting downvoted almost immediately... the most likely explanation was fge downvoting both other answers (He has all the right to do so but an explanation would have been most welcome).

Comment: @Benoit a lazy quantifier must "ask" the next regex component whether it can match the next characer before it matches it itself. Some regex engines will optimize this (for instance, for this particular case, some regex engines will decide to not match a digit in `\w+?` because what comes next is a digit, but these regex engines are the minority). In any case, it is best to define your input so you _do not rely_ on this behavior. Here, you want to match one or more letters -- `[a-zA-Z]+`. This is faster even for optimized engines, and won't leave "old" regex engines astray.

Comment: @fge, how is it different from greedy quantifiers? greedy quantifiers must also ask the next regex component to match… Of course in that particular case, with your solution, it will be right the first time, but in the general case?

Comment: @Benoit it is different because greedy/normal quantifiers do not have to ask _whether the next component matches_, they only care about themselves, and give back only if they have to. They don't have to ask the next component of the regex whether they have a match.